# How can I add two existing models in an Ecto join table?

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

I have Practitioners and Products. A Practitioner has many Products and a Product has many Practitioners. So I try to join them at a ProductPractitioners table.
But I get a `can´t be blank` error when I try to save. What´s the correct approach to join two existing entities in a join table?

## Models

**products_practitioners**

```
 10   schema "products_practitioners" do
 11     belongs_to :product, Product
 12     belongs_to :practitioner, Practitioner
 13
 14     timestamps()
 15   end

 18   def changeset(products_practitioners, attrs) do
 19     products_practitioners
 20     # TODO: Don´t accept invalid params here
 21     |> cast(attrs, [])
 22     |> validate_required([:product, :practitioner])
 23   end
```

**products**

```
 10   schema "products" do
 11     field :name, :string
 12     many_to_many :practitioners, Practitioner, join_through: ProductsPractitioners
 13
 14     timestamps()
 15   end
```

**practitioners**

```
 11   schema "practitioners" do
 12     field :first_name, :string
 13     field :last_name, :string
 14
 15     has_one :calendar, Calendar
 16     many_to_many :products, Product, join_through: ProductsPractitioners
 17
 18     timestamps()
 19   end
```

## IEX Code building practitioners and products

```
iex(11)> {:ok, product} = Factory.product_factory |> Booking.Repo.insert


iex(12)> {:ok, practictioner} = Factory.practitioner_factory |> Booking.Repo.insert


   iex(13)>  attrs = %{product: product, practictioner: practictioner}
%{
  practictioner: %Booking.Practitioners.Practitioner{
    __meta__: #Ecto.Schema.Metadata<:loaded, "practitioners">,
    id: "52dc8f9e-d3b4-4ce5-9016-6a3ef07679e2",
    first_name: "Judd",
    last_name: "Klocko",
    calendar: #Ecto.Association.NotLoaded<association :calendar is not loaded>,
    products: #Ecto.Association.NotLoaded<association :products is not loaded>,
    inserted_at: ~N[2022-12-10 09:31:21],
    updated_at: ~N[2022-12-10 09:31:21]
  },
  product: %Booking.Products.Product{
    __meta__: #Ecto.Schema.Metadata<:loaded, "products">,
    id: "bcb98f0e-e5a2-40cb-bd9a-0eac62ddf0a8",
    name: "qui",
    practitioners: #Ecto.Association.NotLoaded<association :practitioners is not loaded>,
    inserted_at: ~N[2022-12-10 09:31:40],
    updated_at: ~N[2022-12-10 09:31:40]
  }
}
```

**IEX Code trying to add them in a join table**

```
iex(14)> %ProductsPractitioners{}|> ProductsPractitioners.changeset(attrs)|> Repo.insert()
{:error,
 #Ecto.Changeset<
   action: :insert,
   changes: %{},
   errors: [
     product: {"can't be blank", [validation: :required]},
     practitioner: {"can't be blank", [validation: :required]}
   ],
   data: #Booking.Products.ProductsPractitioners<>,
   valid?: false
 >}
```

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that I can't pass in an entire object.
This works:

```
 attrs = %{product_id: product.id, practitioner_id: practictioner.id}
```